# Crystal Reports add a database field to string date

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a field `{OperationHeader.ReceiptDate}` in my report which saves the date of the document in a string (e. g. "07.04.2014") . I need to create a formula which adds to this field  another database field `{OperationDetails.GoodsPriceOut10}` containing a number.

Comment: so what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Split the string into array with day, month and year strings with `Split` function
2. get the date using the array cells with `Date` function
3. use `DateAdd` function to add dates

---

```
StringVar array datestr := Split({OperationHeader.ReceiptDate}, ".");

DateAdd("d", {OperationDetails.GoodsPriceOut10}, Date(ToNumber(datestr[3]), ToNumber(datestr[2]), ToNumber(datestr[1])));
```